# Issue with Insert or Posting Data with single or double quotes

Tags: php, mysql

Still very new to mysqli / php and am building a form for data entry. When I post the data and then go back to view it, anytime there was a single quote (') or double-quote ("), it down displays with a slash in front of it.

For example, if I insert   Hadrian's Wall, it comes back and displays as Hadrian\'s Wall. How would one have it display as it was originally intended.

Also, each time I update it, it adds more slashes. So the first time I updated Hadrian's Wall, it became Hadrian\'s Wall. The second time it became Hadrian\'s Wall, the third time it became Hadrian\\'s Wall and so on.

My post.php file code is:

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', "*****");
define('DB_USER', "*****");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "*****");
define('DB_TABLE', "*****");

// The procedural way
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TABLE);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$lvmID = $_POST['lvmID']; 
$toestelID = $_POST['toestelID']; 
$toestel = $_POST['toestel'];
$erlr = $_POST['erlr'];
$inschrijvingnmr = $_POST['inschrijvingnmr'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$cn = $_POST['cn'];
$ln = $_POST['ln'];
$delivered = $_POST['delivered'];
$vliegtuignaam = $_POST['vliegtuignaam'];
$became = $_POST['became'];
$vorigeLVMID = $_POST['vorigeLVMID'];
$vorigeInschrijv = $_POST['vorigeInschrijv'];
$firstflight = $_POST['firstflight'];
$engines = $_POST['engines'];
$configuratie = $_POST['configuratie'];
$remark = $_POST['remark'];
$specialekleuren = $_POST['specialekleuren'];
$fleetnmr = $_POST['fleetnmr'];
$inactive = $_POST['inactive'];
$exitdate = $_POST['exitdate'];
$beeld = $_POST['beeld'];
$beeld_linkje = $_POST['beeld_linkje'];
$beeld_copyright = $_POST['beeld_copyright'];
$photouse_approve = $_POST['photouse_approve'];
$photouse_approve_date = $_POST['photouse_approve_date'];
$beeld_comment = $_POST['beeld_comment'];
$seatmap = $_POST['seatmap'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "
UPDATE tbl_vliegtuiggegevens SET lvmID=?, toestelID=?, toestel=?, erlr=?, inschrijvingnmr=?, status=?, cn=?, ln=?, delivered=?, vliegtuignaam=?, became=?, vorigeLVMID=?, vorigeInschrijv=?, firstflight=?, engines=?, configuratie=?, remark=?, specialekleuren=?, fleetnmr=?, inactive=?, exitdate=?, beeld=?, beeld_linkje=?, beeld_copyright=?, photouse_approve=?, photouse_approve_date=?, beeld_comment=?, seatmap=? WHERE vliegtuiggegevenID=?";
if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)))
{
  die("Unable to prepare statement");
}
else
{
  $stmt->bind_param("iisssssssssisssssssissssssssi", $lvmID, $toestelID, $toestel, $erlr, $inschrijvingnmr, $status, $cn, $ln, $delivered, $vliegtuignaam, $became, $vorigeLVMID, $vorigeInschrijv, $firstflight, $engines, $configuratie, $remark, $specialekleuren, $fleetnmr, $inactive, $exitdate, $beeld, $beeld_linkje, $beeld_copyright, $photouse_approve, $photouse_approve_date, $beeld_comment, $seatmap, $id);    
  if($stmt->execute())
  {
    echo "Successfully updated";
  }
  else
  {
    die("Update failed");
  }
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

On the form page that I use to enter the data, my code for one of the forms fields is:

```
 <input type="text" name="vliegtuignaam" size="40" value="<? echo   
 "$row[vliegtuignaam]"?>">
```

On the display page, this same field for display would be:

```
 <td><strong>Vliegtuignaam: </strong></td>
 <td><? echo "$row[vliegtuignaam]"?></td>
```

When I try something like   it just outputs stripslashes(Hadrian\'s Wall) instead of Hadrian's Wall.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: yes, I have read this before and it just doesn't make sense to me. This was never an issue for me with just mysql, but now with mysqli it's such a headache. I don't know where these functions can go.

Comment: why does it not make sense?

Comment: What do you mean, it literally outputs `stripslashes(Hadrian\'s Wall)`? Including the function name? Make sure you're not placing the `stripslashes` part in a string.

Comment: Here, give this a whirl `<td><? echo stripslashes($row[vliegtuignaam]);?></td>` or  `<td><? echo stripslashes($row['vliegtuignaam']);?></td>` @DaniëlCronk

Comment: thank you, Fred. That was correct. The information below helped explain this to me. regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"When I try something like it just outputs stripslashes(Hadrian\'s Wall)"*

What you probably tried to do was `<td><? echo "stripslashes($row[vliegtuignaam])"?></td>` which is incorrect.

That is why it's showing you the function name because the function is set inside quotes.

What you need to use is:

```
<td><? echo stripslashes($row['vliegtuignaam']);?></td>
```

or

```
<td><? echo stripslashes($row[vliegtuignaam]);?></td>
```

if the quotes inside the array gives you a hard time.

As per an example in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

```
echo stripslashes($str);
```

Full example:

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

---

What you could do and as another option, would be to use `stripslashes()` on the variable(s) before it gets to the query.

```
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

$newstring = stripslashes($str);
```

then go ahead with the insert.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. This helped me understand the concept.

Comment: @DaniëlCronk You're welcome Daniël, glad to have been of help, *cheers*